# AVFoundation question - iPhone SDK

Tags: iphone, objective-c

What's the best way to grab a succession of images from the camera using the AV Foundation framework? I am only interested in what an iPhone 3G can support. I haven't been able to find any information on which classes are not supported on the iPhone 3G (without video capability).

Has anyone had any experience with this?

Many thanks,
Brett

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All classes are supported on the iPhone 3G. The difference lies in the maximum supported resolution and frame rates as well as in missing hardware capabilities (auto focus, torch, front camera etc.).

If you're a registered developer, you can watch session 409 of the WWDC (https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2010/). They present a few slides where they compare the capabilites and limitations of the different devices.

This presentation also shows all the ingredients needed to grab a succession of images.